# HTTP Error 400.13: Still getting just the structure of my files, even after enabling Directory Browsing on IIS7.0!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

Each time I deploy my application either on my laptop (Vista) or on my desktop(XP), I'm getting the following error: **"HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory"**. After doing some researches, I'm advised to enable "**Directory Browsing**". But, instead of getting the application run, I'm getting a blank page with the structure of my application.

Something like:

```
10/7/2010  7:35 AM        <dir> ExternalAssemblies
10/7/2010 10:41 AM        <dir> MyApplication.Domain
10/7/2010 10:43 AM        <dir> MyApplication.WebUI
10/7/2010 11:04 AM          168 web.config
```

I've tried also to do what it's said on [this article from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942062), but I still get the above result.

I've started to suspect the structure of the package I put in the server folder. In fact, when I create an application that has the primitive structure (the one you get when you create a new application), then it works. But, if I add one or more class library, the I get the above error. I'm not sure where the problem lay, but I suspect that aspect.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, but shouldn't your IIS web folder perhaps be pointing at `MyApplication.WebUI` instead?

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error: "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'." I think we're getting somwhere.

Comment: Thanks the error Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' had to do with Sql Server. I put the right credentials and everything works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have a default document.

As far as I can see, the directory listing looks just like it should.

Comment: What that default document should be or look like? When I access the "Default Document", I can see several propositions, such as Default.htm, Default.aspx,Index.html, etc... Knowing that we are doing ASP.NET MVC, I don't just know where those default pages fit.